# Is it possible to add a table view controller to a part of a view controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Let's say that I have a *UITableViewController* which is mostly reusable, and should be used from many *UIViewController*s, but it should cover only part of the total view (e.g. 90% of the total height). Normally I would do this with navigation, but if I want to keep the top 10% of the UIViewController visible, and show the *UITableViewController* for the remaining 90%, it is possible and if yes how to do it?

Comment: There’s nothing special about a table view controller in this regard. Just about any view controller can be contained in another.

Comment: And you would do that using a container view – dragging one into a view controller, you can connect the container view to your table view controller making it a child view controller of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The big view controller is container view controller, and the small view controller (table view controller in this case) is child view controller. We can add or remove child view controller in the container view controller.

Add a child view controller to a container

```
- (void)displayContentController:(UIViewController *)content {
   [self addChildViewController:content];
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController];
   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Remove a child view controller from a container

```
- (void)hideContentController:(UIViewController *)content {
   [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
   [content.view removeFromSuperview];
   [content removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

We can also remove an old child view controller and add a new child view controller at the same time. Here is the example code (with animation).

```
- (void)cycleFromViewController:(UIViewController *)oldVC
               toViewController:(UIViewController *)newVC {
   // Prepare the two view controllers for the change.
   [oldVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
   [self addChildViewController:newVC];

   // Get the start frame of the new view controller and the end frame
   // for the old view controller. Both rectangles are offscreen.
   newVC.view.frame = [self newViewStartFrame];
   CGRect endFrame = [self oldViewEndFrame];

   // Queue up the transition animation.
   [self transitionFromViewController:oldVC toViewController:newVC
        duration:0.25 options:0
        animations:^{
            // Animate the views to their final positions.
            newVC.view.frame = oldVC.view.frame;
            oldVC.view.frame = endFrame;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
           // Remove the old view controller and send the final
           // notification to the new view controller.
           [oldVC removeFromParentViewController];
           [newVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        }];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. Just add UITableViewController as child controller to your parent UIViewController.

Also, you can read about it here [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)